# How can I fix an issue on a Python Flask app on ec2 only where data from a table in database won't display?

Tags: python, flask, amazon-ec2

On the dashboard page of my app, for some reason, it is unable to obtain any data from the "cars" table in the database. I was able to narrow this issue down to only existing on the dashboard page, of the app on the ec2. If I run on a local server it works fine. If I try to go to the route /show/<car_id> it retrieves the information about a specific vehicle fine.

```
@classmethod
    def getAllCars(cls):
        query = "SELECT * FROM cars AS c LEFT JOIN users AS u ON u.id = c.users_id;"
        results = connectToMySQL(cls.db).query_db(query)
        all_cars = []
        if not results:
            return all_cars
        for car in results:
            new_car = cls(car)
            userData = { 
                'id': car['users_id'],
                'first_name': car['first_name'],
                'last_name': car['last_name'],
                'email': car['email'],
                'password': car['password'],
                'created_at': car['u.created_at'],
                'updated_at': car['u.updated_at']
            }
            userD = user.User(userData)
            print(userD)
            new_car.user = userD
            all_cars.append(new_car)
        return all_cars
```

```
@app.route("/dashboard")
def dashboard():
    if "user_id" not in session:
        return redirect("/")
    data = {
        "id": session["user_id"]
    }
    return render_template("dashboard.html", user = User.getSingleUser(data), all_cars = Car.getAllCars())
```

```html
<table class="table table-dark tabled-striped w-75">
            <thead class="border-bottom">
                <th class="w-25">Model</th>
                <th class="w-25">Year</th>
                <th class="w-25">Seller</th>
                <th class="w-25">Actions</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {% for car in all_cars %}
                <tr>
                        <td class="w-25">{{car.model}}</td>
                        <td class="w-25">{{car.year}}</td>
                        <td class="w-25">{{car.user.first_name}} {{car.user.last_name}}</td>
                        <td class="w-25">
                            <a href="/show/{{car.id}}" class="btn btn-success">View</a>
                        {% if session["user_id"] == car.users_id %}    
                            <a href="/edit/{{car.id}}" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</a>
                            <a href="/delete/{{car.id}}" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
                        {% endif %}
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

A screen shot of what I get locally vs ec2.

[image: Running app locally]

[image: ec2]

Comment: What does `connectToMySQL` do if the connection fails or times out? Does it throw an exception or simply return false? At a guess it returns false and your view then simply shows an empty list of cars. Did you debug this, specifically the connection and, if that worked, then the SQL request/response? Did you run your Flask app in debug mode to surface errors?

Comment: yes, I've debugged this, and if there is a connection failure it will return false. For whatever reason, this problem only exists with trying to pull from the cars table on the dashboard if I go to say /show/18 (which is a valid car id) I would get get a page displaying all of the information about the vehicle in the cars table. I will go add the debug back in and do a check.

Comment: Added debug=True app.run( debug=True) in wsgi.py and the app worked. oddly it didn't the last time I had it there. You should put what you suggested as an answer so I can accept that.

Comment: this app was never going to go into a production state, so being in debug mode works fine for me. Now I can start working on other features I've put off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If possible, I would run the Flask app in debug mode to surface errors.

Also, I would debug the `connectToMySQL` and `query_db` methods. Are they returning the correct things? If your query actually returns falsey to indicate an error then your view will simply show an empty list of cars (because that's what the code defaults to, via `all_cars = []`).